# Here you are or here it is

Tags: syntactic-analysis

In an interview I heard " Examiner:  May I see your passport please ? Student: Yes, here you are. " Why wasn't the answer ', Yes, here it is. '? Is the full version of the answer " Yes, here you are going to have it" ?

Comment: Either wording is fine in a large number of situations.  There are a few where one version or the other might be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

"Here you are" is a very common saying when handing something to someone. There is no "full version".

> here you are
>
> (informal) used when you are giving something to somebody

[Here (Oxford)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/here_1)